# Python Dictionary file not translating into array

Tags: python

I'm loading a file with words and definitions each on their own line separated by colons. Here is a sample.

```
Dissaray:A state of confusion and disorderliness
Staid:Steady and serious
Contemptible:Unworthy, wretched, mean
Intertwine:To connect or associate two things
Unwarranted:Not based on truth or valid circumstances
Punctuate:To specifically point out
Validate:To state the soundness or truth of something
Conducive:To contribute in a useful way
```

I'm trying to read the file with this code:

```
print("Currently loading file for your level")
dictionary = {}
with open("level"+str(level)+".txt","r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
        line.split(":")
        dictionary[line[0]] = line[1]
print("Dictionary file has been loaded")
print(dictionary)
```

The lines print correctly, but when I print the `dictionary` array, I get this.
`{'A': 'p', 'C': 'o', 'B': 'e', 'E': 'm', 'D': 'e', 'G': 'r', 'F': 'i', 'I': 'r', 'H': 'i', 'J': 'o', 'M': 'i', 'L': 'u', 'O': 'p', 'N': 'o', 'P': 'a', 'S': 'u', 'R': 'e', 'U': 'n', 'T': 'r', 'W': 'a', 'V': 'e', 'Z': 'e'}`

I'm not sure what's happening here, can someone please help?

Comment: `line = line.split(...)`. `split` returns the result rather than editing the original string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split` doesn't work in place. You need to assign it to `line`, otherwise, you'll be indexing the original line:

```
for line in f:
   line = line.split(":")
   dictionary[line[0]] = line[1]
```

More so, you could also simply do:

```
dictionary = dict(line.split(':') for line in f)
```

Building the dictionary from a generator expression.

Comment: The dictionary comprehension is definitely better if you're sure the input is correct, but the explicit version does have the nice feature of throwing an exception if there's no `:` (but it doesn't check for there being more than one).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.split()` returns its value rather than modifying its argument. Actually it has to do that, because strings are immutable in Python. So you just need to change:

```
line.split(":")
dictionary[line[0]] = line[1]
```

to

```
line_parts = line.split(":")
dictionary[line_parts[0]] = line_parts[1]
```